# Sort consecutive elements based on duration time C++

Tags: c++, sorting

I'm working on a code that requires me to do the following,
given two vectors:

```
arrival  : 0 0 1 8 9 10 20 20 30 40 41 42 42 43 44 
duration : 4 3 1 5 3 1  15 2  2  5  3  1  16 3  1
```

I'm trying to iterate over the vectors and when I find two or more consecutive elements, I need to sort them according to their duration in ascending order. 
So the output should be the following:

```
arrival  : 0 0 1 8 9 10 20 20 30 40 41 42 42 43 44
duration : 3 4 1 5 3 1  2  15 2  5  3  1  16 3  1
```

As you can see, the duration for the first two 0's has been swapped. 
However, somehow it's swapping 16 with 1 for the arrival time 42

```
int p[pnum];
int temp;
for(int i=1;i<=pnum;i++){p[i] = i;}

for(int i=0;i<pnum;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<pnum;j++)
    {
        if(arrival[i]<arrival[j])
        {
            temp=p[j];
            p[j]=p[i];
            p[i]=temp;
            temp=arrival[j];
            arrival[j]=arrival[i];
            arrival[i]=temp;
            temp=duration[j];
            duration[j]=duration[i];
            duration[i]=temp;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I fix this to get the right output? please help!

Comment: side note: instead of using a temporary you can use [`std::swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap)

Comment: How about starting the inner for loop from `1` instead of a `0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put arrival and duration in an `std::pair<int,int>` and put that pair in a `std::set`, they will be sorted as expected.  If needed, you can make 2 new vectors with the sorted values.

A bit cleaner would be to use a struct with the needed fields, but then you should define a compare function to decide the order.